# Run spark-shell from sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-shell

The default way of getting spark shell seems to be [to download the distribution from the website](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html). Yet,  [this spark issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11832) mentions that it can be installed via `sbt`. I could not find documentation on this. In a sbt project that uses `spark-sql` and `spark-core`, no `spark-shell` binary was found.

How do you run `spark-shell` from sbt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the following URL:

https://bzhangusc.wordpress.com/2015/11/20/use-sbt-console-as-spark-shell/

> If you already using Sbt for your project, it’s very simple to setup Sbt Console to replace Spark-shell command.
> Let’s start from the basic case. When you setup the project with sbt, you can simply run the console as `sbt console`
>
> Within the console, you just need to initiate SparkContext and SQLContext to make it behave like Spark Shell

```scala
scala> val sc = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext("localhell")
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```